# Is it possible to call a constructor from a class to another, and perform mathematical operation, and return its results, in Java?

Tags: java, constructor

I would like to know if Java allows you to call a constructor from a different class, and perform mathematical operations on it. And return its results in the Main class.

For example, I have

```
public class Wallet {

private int dollar;

public Wallet(int dollar){
this.dollar = dollar;
}
```

I also have

```
public class Count {

private int counter;
private ArrayList<Wallet> wallet;

public Count(){
       this.wallet = new ArrayList<Wallet>();
}

public void addWallets(Wallet dollar) {
       this.wallet.add(dollar);
    }

public int sum(){
return 0;}
```

Now, my goal is to add the amount of money in each wallet, and print the results. This is the main class.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) { 
Count count = new Count();

Wallet wallet1 = new Wallet(34);
Waller wallet2 = new Wallet(26);

count.addWallets(wallet1);
count.addWallets(wallet2);

System.out.println( "Total is: " + count.sum() );
 }
 }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is that a home work?

Comment: @PrashantZombade no. I'm self-taught.

Comment: Ok. The question you asked and your expected result in the code, do not match. Do you know the difference between method and constructor?

Comment: @PrashantZombade I know the difference. I created this problem. Which part doesn't match?

Comment: `call a constructor from a class to another` what exactly do you mean here? BTW I have answer ready of your program.

Comment: @PrashantZombade I mean I want to call the constructer Wallet(int dollar) from the class Wallet to the method sum() which is in the Class Count. I hope I made sense.

Comment: In sum() method you can create object of Wallet class like Wallet wt=new Wallet(10) it will internally call the  constructor of Wallet but not possible to call explicitly.You can call in super class and same class using this and super keyword.

Answer (score 0):

**The question you asked is quite unclear. But I will try to help you.**

> goal is to add the amount of money in each wallet, and print the
>   results.

1. Have a getter and setter methods for `dollar` in your `Wallet` class. So that you can use them later in the program.
2. In sum method `sum` of the dollars from each `Wallet`.

Here is the solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Count count = new Count();

        Wallet wallet1 = new Wallet(34);
        Wallet wallet2 = new Wallet(26);

        count.addWallets(wallet1);
        count.addWallets(wallet2);

        System.out.println("Total is: " + count.sum());
    }
}

class Count {

    private int counter;
    private ArrayList<Wallet> wallet;

    public Count() {
        this.wallet = new ArrayList<Wallet>();
    }

    public void addWallets(Wallet dollar) {
        this.wallet.add(dollar);
    }

    public int sum() {
        int sum = 0;

        for(Wallet w : wallet) {
            sum += w.getDollar();
        }

        return sum;
    }
}

class Wallet {

    private int dollar;

    Wallet(int dollar){
    this.dollar = dollar;
    }

    public int getDollar() {
        return dollar;
    }

    public void setDollar(int dollar) {
        this.dollar = dollar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the working of a list.

When you are running below code,

```
count.addWallets(wallet1);
count.addWallets(wallet2);
```

It adds wallet1 and wallet2 to `ArrayList<Wallet> wallet` of count as two separate elements.

When you are calling`count.sum()`, that method will always return 0 based on your method declaration. If you want to get the sum of all elements when you are calling that method, try declaring the method as below:

```
public int sum(){
    int total =0;
    for(int i=0;i< wallet.size();i++){
         total = total + wallet.get(i).getDollar();
    }
    return total;
}
```

And add setters and getters in your Wallet class for Dollar as

```
public int getDollar() {
    return dollar;
}

public void setDollar(int dollar) {
    this.dollar = dollar;
}
```

That way when you call the method, it gets the sum of dollars in all wallets and returns you.

Answer (score 0):

In sum() method you can create object of Wallet class like Wallet wt=new Wallet(10) it will internally call the constructor of Wallet but not possible to call explicitly.You can call in super class and same class using this and super keyword.